# IndexError in simple list processing function - what am I missing?

Tags: python

This is one of those embarassing pieces of code that simply needs a second pair of eyes to spot the "obvious" mistake. I am processing a list of lists, and for some reason, I am hitting a 'List Index out of range' erorr - and I can't spot it despite peering at the screen for a while.

Here is the snippet:

```
def group_ldata(data, freq, normal_grouping = True):
    if freq > 1 and len(data) > (SOME_SANITY_FACTOR*freq):
        i, output, subset, lastpos = (0, [],[], len(data)-freq)
        if not normal_grouping:
            for i in range(lastpos):
                pass
        else:
            while True:
                subset = data[i:freq]
                #print subset
                firstrow = subset[0]
                lastrow = subset[-1]
                output.append((firstrow[0], firstrow[1], lastrow[2]))
                i += freq
                if i >= lastpos:
                    break
        return output
    else:
        return data
```

Here's some sample data to boot:

```
>>> a =[]
>>> a.append(range(0,5))
>>> a.append(range(5,10))
>>> a.append(range(10,15))
>>> a.append(range(15,20))
>>> a.append(range(20,25))
>>> a.append(range(25,30))
>>> a.append(range(30,35))
```

Here is the result when I run it:

```
>>> b = group_ldata(a,2)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in group_ldata
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone spot what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But, the reason for the error is obvious.

In the beginning, you do `i=0`.
Then, later in the `while True` loop, you do `i += freq`. So, now i `equals` freq.

Now, when the `while True` loop runs again (2nd iteration), in the line `subset = data[i:freq]`, subset will be equal to a list with lenght 0. And you are trying to access the first element of that. Makes sense?

Comment: Bingo!. I knew it would be something silly like that - well spotted!. The upper limit should be i + freq.